# perl code behaving strange

Tags: string, perl

I have written a code to get the url of a website and then search for a string and then compare that string(actually a number) with a hardcoded number

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::Simple;

my  $oldversion =36;


$pageURL="http://www.google.com/isos/preFCS5.3/LATESTGOODCVP/";   
my $simplePage=get($pageURL);  


my $newPage = "$simplePage";
my $str = (split("href=\"CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.",$newPage ))[1];

my $version = substr("$str",0,2);

print $version;               // HERE IT PRINT 37 WHICH IS CORRECT


if($version =! $oldVersion )
{


print $version;               // BUT HERE IT PRINTS 1 WHICH IS WRONG. HOW IS IT CHANGING ?

##-- fetch the zip and save it as perlhowto.zip
my $status = getstore("http://www.google.com/isos/preFCS5.3/LATESTGOODCVP/CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.$version.iso", "CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.$version.iso");
}
else
{
print("Currently new version\n");
}
```

Why is it changing the value ? its not able to download the file becuase of that.

Comment: Is this cut and pasted from your actual code? A variable seems to change name from $oldversion to $oldVersion. And you appear to be using the wrong type of comments. And why aren't you using "use strict" and "use warnings"? It's so much easier to help if you can be bothered to post code that actually compiles.

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of the script, fix the errors and warnings, then post the new code.

Comment: [Always. Use. Strict. And. Always. Use. Warnings.](http://joelslinux.blogspot.com/2011/06/use-strict-and-warnings.html)

Answer (score 4):

You mean `!=`, not `=!`, which is an assignment of a negation.

Also, split always uses a regex (except for the very special case of a string that has a single space), so those `.`s in `5.3.0.` will match any non-newline.  You probably want to `\`-escape them.

You may be interested in the uscan script in the debian devtools package.

Comment: Ok, I changed it, but its still not able to compare, If both the numbers are equal, its still downloading the file, instead of coming out of IF loop .

Answer (score 3):

You have got your "not equals" operator backwards.  It should be `!=` rather than `=!`.

By using `=!` you are in effect saying "set $version to the negated value of $oldversion".

Here is the offending line

```
if($version =! $oldVersion )  # Should be if($version != $oldVersion )
```

Also notice that by using the != operator you are telling perl that $version and $oldversion contain numbers.  For string comparisons you should use the `ne` operator, which assumes that these variables contain strings.

```
if($version ne $oldVersion )  # String inequality
```

Here is the documentation for equality operators -

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators

Comment: hi, I want to compare numbers here. Is there anyway I can conver string to numbers ?

Comment: @mac You don't have to convert datatypes in perl, it is done automatically, if it is possible. `if ($str == $text)` will automatically try to convert `$str` and `$text` to numbers. If it cannot be done, perl will warn **if** you have warnings turned on. If you have warnings turned off - like you have - it does not warn, and becomes a bug that can be hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are *assigning* to `$version` the value `!$oldVersion` in this "test":

```
if($version =! $oldVersion )
```

And `$oldVersion` is nothing--but `$oldversion` is 37. You are assigning `$version` the boolean negation of an *undefined* variable. Undefined is boolean false, and so the negation is boolean true or 1.

If you read very much on perl, you're bound to come across the advice to use `strict` and `warnings`. Had you done that, it would have told you, among other things:

```
Global symbol "$oldVersion" requires explicit package name at - line 21.
```

This means that you didn't declare `$oldVersion` as lexical (`my`) or package-level (`our`) in this package, so if you want to use it, please include the package where you're getting it. In a vast majority of cases, a seasoned Perl programmer will recognize this as "Ugh, I didn't declare `$oldVersion`!" and the reason is that you declared $old**v**ersion.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of split doesn't make a lot of sense here.  What you really want are the two digits following the `CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.` string.  You're also not really doing anything by assigning one variable to another with the addition of quotes (`$newPage = "$simplePage"`).

And, of course, as others have pointed out, the comparison is `!=` not `=!`.

I'd rewrite this as:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $oldVersion = 36;
my $url        = 'http://www.google.com/isos/preFCS5.3/LATESTGOODCVP/';

my $newPage = get($url)
    or die "Cannot retrieve contents from $url\n";

if ( $newPage =~ /href=\"CVP-LATEST-5\.3\.0\.(\d\d)/ ) {
    my $version = $1;

    if ( $version != $oldVersion ) {
        my $status = getstore($url . "CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.$version.iso",
                              "CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.$version.iso");
    } else {
        print "Already at most recent version\n";
    }

} else {
    die "Cannot find version tag in contents from $url\n";
}
```